# Mysterious 'function' being attached to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have the following code:

```js
    // button sets
    var sets = ['.diamond-colour','.diamond-cut','.diamond-clarity','.diamond-certificate'];
    // for each set
    for (set in sets){
        console.log('Set: '+set);
        console.log(sets[set]);
    }
```

The console log shows:

```js
Set: 0
.diamond-colour
Set: 1
.diamond-cut
Set: 2
.diamond-clarity
Set: 3
.diamond-certificate
Set: findIndex
function (value){
var ctr = "";
for (var i=0; i < this.length; i++) {
if (this[i] == value) {
return i;
}
}
return ctr;
}
```

It appears to be a new array element with the key of `findIndex` and a value being that function.

Would anyone have any idea what this is and why it's appearing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a traditional `for` loop to iterate over an array, otherwise you may pick up properties (in this case a new function) added by yours or 3rd-party code.

```
for(var i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {
```

As others have mentioned, caching the length provides optimal performance:

```
for(var i = 0, len=sets.length; i < len; i++) {
```

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < sets.length; i++) {` will far out-perform `for (set in sets){`. Here is a performance test: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2. Also note that if you cache the length of the array it will perform even faster: `for(var i = 0, len = sets.length; i < len; i++) {`

Comment: @Jasper Interesting tests. I had no idea `for..in` would be *that much* slower.

Comment: @Jasper My point was *don't use for...in for arrays* but that is certainly useful information.

Answer (score 4):

This is because the `in` operator with for loops in Javascript loops over the properties of the object, not just the objects in the "Array". I say "Array" because Javascript arrays are really just objects with numeric properties created for each entry in the array (and some additional methods and properties like `.length`).

As Dennis mentioned, you'll want to use a traditional for loop to loop over just the objects in the array.

Also note that an easy optimisation for such for loops is to initialise the length value once at the start of the loop, rather than evaluating `array.length` each time:

```
for (var i = 0, len = sets.length; i < len; i++) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: +1 for caching the length of the array. This helps it perform faster, see this performance test for proof: http://jsperf.com/jquery-each-vs-for-loops/2

Comment: ECMAScript 5th edition does provide a mechanism to annotate properties as non-enumerable, however. (But iterating by index is still the semantically-correct method.)

Comment: @pst Good to know, but how long until ECMAScript 5th ed support is widespread enough to promote it as a valid, compatible solution? Iterating this way should work in current 4th ed and future 5th ed versions, correct?

Comment: @GregL That method is *always* the correct method to iterate through indices in an Array ;-) I generally don't perform the "cache", but that's more of a stylistic issue in most cases. I was merely trying to point of how `for..in` semantics can be altered in some cases (and why things like `length` won't show up in new browsers).